# OpenCV: How to capture frames from an Ethernet camera

Tags: c++, opencv, ethernet, ip-camera

I have earlier programmed USB webcam, where the sole aim is to get the live frames from the camera and display in a window.  I used cvCaptureFromCAM for that purpose, which worked fine for USB Camera(see code below).

I want to know how do I capture frames from a Gigabit Ethernet camera?  I guess I need to capture frames from some default IP address using some API. Can some one point me to right direction?

I will be using C++ with OpenCV on Windows 7 on an Intel i3 processor.

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include <stdio.h>

// A Simple Camera Capture Framework 
int main() {
    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( CV_CAP_ANY );
    if ( !capture ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: capture is NULL \n" );
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }

    // Create a window in which the captured images will be presented
    cvNamedWindow( "mywindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

    // Show the image captured from the camera in the window and repeat
    while ( 1 ) {
        // Get one frame
        IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );

        if ( !frame ) {
            fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: frame is null...\n" );
            getchar();
            break;
        }

        cvShowImage( "mywindow", frame );

        // Do not release the frame!
        // If ESC key pressed, Key=0x10001B under OpenCV 0.9.7(linux version),
        // remove higher bits using AND operator
        if ( (cvWaitKey(10) & 255) == 27 ) break;
    }

    // Release the capture device housekeeping
    cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
    cvDestroyWindow( "mywindow" );
    return 0;
}
```

**Update**

So now I am able to display the live images in the vendor provided software GUI. But still I want to display the image (and possibly video) using the IP address of the camera.

When I know the IP address of the camera, why can't I access the data (images) sent by the camera and display on browser? I tried typing the ip address of the camera (i.e 192.169.2.3) on my browser (192.169.2.4), but it say "page not found". What does it mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV with Network Cameras](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712998/opencv-with-network-cameras)

Comment: It's also a possible duplicate of [OpenCV with GigE Vision Cameras](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345467/opencv-with-gige-vision-cameras).

Answer (score 11):

You can do this with genIcam API. genIcam is a generic interface for cameras (USB, GigE, CameraLink, etc.). It consists of multiple modules but we'll focus on GenTL (transport layer). You can read more on GenTL documentation [HERE](http://www.emva.org/wp-content/uploads/GenICam_GenTL_1_5.pdf). I recommend using either the Basler API or the Baumer API, which are GenTL consumers (producers and consumers are described in the GenTL docs). I used the Baumer API, but both should work.

NOTE: I'm using a Baumer HXG20 mono.

**THINGS TO DOWNLOAD AND INSTALL**

1. Visual Studios Community eddition (I used 2015 [LINK](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/))
2. Baumer GAPI SDK, [LINK](http://www.baumer.com/us-en/products/identification-image-processing/software-and-starter-kits/baumer-gapi-sdk/)
3. openCV (here is a youtube tutorial to build openCV 3 for c++) [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7SM5OD2pZKY)

**TEST CAMERA WITH CAMERA EXPLORER**

It's good to verify your network interface card (NIC) and camera are working and play around in the Camera Explorer program. You may need to enable Jumbo Packets on your NIC. You can configure the camera IP using the IPconfig program as well (either DHCP or static IP).

**SETUP VISUAL STUDIOS**

Setting up your environment variables and configuring Visual studios is described in the Baumer GAPI SDK programmers guide (chapter 4), located in the following directory

`C:\Program Files\Baumer\Baumer GAPI SDK\Docs\Programmers_Guide`

- Check that you have the following system variable (if using 64 bit version), or create the variable if needed (refer to section 4.3.1 in the programmer's guide).
- name = `GENICAM_GENTL64_PATH`
- value = `C:\Program Files\Baumer\Baumer GAPI SDK\Components\Bin\x64\`
- In visual Studios, create a new C++ project and update the following properties (refer to section 4.4.1 in the programmer's guide).
- C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories = `C:\Program Files\Baumer\Baumer GAPI SDK\Components\Dev\C++\Inc`
- Linker >  General > Additional Library Directories = `C:\Program Files\Baumer\Baumer GAPI SDK\Components\Dev\C++\Lib\x64`
- Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies = `bgapi2_genicam.lib`
- Build Events > Post-Build Event > Command Line = `copy "C:\Program Files\Baumer\Baumer GAPI SDK\Components\Bin\x64"\*.* .\`

**CREATE A .CPP FILE TO DISPLAY IMAGE STREAM IN AN OPENCV WINDOW**

The simplest way to get started is to use one of the example codes provided in the Baumer GAPI SDK and modify it to add the openCV functionality. The example code to use is 005_PixelTransformation, which is located here

`C:\Program Files\Baumer\Baumer GAPI SDK\Components\Examples\C++\src\0_Common\005_PixelTransformation`

Copy and paste this .cpp file into your project source directory and make sure you can build and compile. It should capture 8 images and print out the first 6 pixel values from the first 6 lines for each image.

Add these `#include` statements to the .cpp source file:

```
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\video\video.hpp>
```

Add these variable declarations at the beginning of the `main()` function

```
// OPENCV VARIABLE DECLARATIONS
cv::VideoWriter cvVideoCreator;                 // Create OpenCV video creator
cv::Mat openCvImage;                            // create an OpenCV image
cv::String videoFileName = "openCvVideo.avi";   // Define video filename
cv::Size frameSize = cv::Size(2048, 1088);      // Define video frame size (frame width x height)
cvVideoCreator.open(videoFileName, CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', 'X'), 20, frameSize, true); // set the codec type and frame rate
```

In the original 005_PixelTransformation.cpp file, line 569 has a `for` loop that loops over 8 images, which says `for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)`. We want to change this to run continuously. I did this by changing it to a `while` loop that says

```
while (pDataStream->GetIsGrabbing())
```

Within our new `while` loop, there's an `if` statement that checks if the Pixel format is 'Mono' (greyscale) or color. In the original file, it starts at line 619 and ends at 692. Directly after the `if` and `else` statement braces are closed, and before the `pImage->Release();` statement, we need to add the openCV portion to display the images to a window. Add the following lines of code

```
}   // This is the closing brace for the 'else color' statement 

// OPEN CV STUFF
openCvImage = cv::Mat(pTransformImage->GetHeight(), pTransformImage->GetWidth(), CV_8U, (int *)pTransformImage->GetBuffer());

// create OpenCV window ----
cv::namedWindow("OpenCV window: Cam", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);

//display the current image in the window ----
cv::imshow("OpenCV window : Cam", openCvImage);
cv::waitKey(1);
```

One thing to note is the pixel format in the `openCvImage` object. My camera is a mono 8 bit, so I need to specify `CV_8U`. If your camera is RGB or 10-bit pixels, you need to provide the correct format (see the openCV documentation [HERE](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-type)).

you can refer to the other examples for adjusting camera parameters.

now once you build and compile, you should have an openCV window open that displays the camera images!

THUMPS UP!!!!

[image: THUMBS UP FOR MORE UP VOTES!!!!!]

Comment: I can confirm this works in a Win32 program Baumer-GAPI 2.8.1 on Win7 64bit sing the Baumer TXG06 camera. Thank you for the inroad.

Comment: @mark Jay, thank you, i stumbled upon this post and am trying to use the GAPI to access another gigevision camera from another brand. The problem I am facing now, is that on one pc "systemList = SystemList::GetInstance();
systemList->Refresh();" returns 0 systems. on another I get 4. both pcs have the same camera connected. Do you know what systems are in the first place? are those network cards? i read through the documentation but was not able to find an answer to this...

Answer (score 3):

You will not be able to access images on the camera if it doesn't have a web server running (check its doco).
try typing this at a command prompt:

```
telnet 192.169.2.3 80
```

If telnet times out, your camera is not running a server on the default port 80.

Also see this question:[C++ code Capturing image from IP / Ethernet Cameras (AXIS Cam)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462323/c-code-capturing-image-from-ip-ethernet-cameras-axis-cam?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

To add to [mark jay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5156102/mark-jay)'s answer (which I can confirm works on Win7x64 inside a Win32 program using Baumer-GAPI2 2.8.1 and the VC10 compiler and a Baumer TXG06 camera). If the camera is set up to grab `Mono8` and you are intending to grab an image of the same format `CV_8UC1`, then in the `005_PixelTransformation.cpp` example you can avoid the creation of `BGAPI2::Image* pTransformImage` and `BGAPI2::Image* pImage` altogether and just build the `cv::Mat` using the buffer memory pointer as in the following excerpt from my `GigE_cam` class:

```
bool GigE_cam::operator>>(cv::Mat& out_mat)
{
    bool success(false);
    try
    {
        _p_buffer_filled = _p_data_stream->GetFilledBuffer(static_cast<bo_uint64>(_timeout_ms));
        if(_p_buffer_filled != 0)
        {
            if(_p_buffer_filled->GetIsIncomplete())
            {
                _p_buffer_filled->QueueBuffer();
            }
            else
            {
                if(_p_buffer_filled->GetPixelFormat() == "Mono8")
                {
                    _image_out_buffer = cv::Mat(static_cast<int>(_p_buffer_filled->GetHeight()), 
                                                static_cast<int>(_p_buffer_filled->GetWidth()), 
                                                CV_8UC1, 
                                                static_cast<uchar*>(_p_buffer_filled->GetMemPtr()));
                    if(_image_out_buffer.data)
                    {
                        _image_out_buffer.copyTo(out_mat);
                        success = true;
                    }
                }
                else if(_p_buffer_filled->GetPixelFormat() == "Mono10")
                {
                    // Todo transform to BGR8 etc. not implemented
                }
                _p_buffer_filled->QueueBuffer(); // Queue buffer after use
            }
        }   
    }
    catch(BGAPI2::Exceptions::IException& ex)
    {
        _last_BGAPI2_error_str = ex.GetType();
    }
    return success;
}
```

This code is getting full frames from the camera (776 X 582 px) at 66.5 fps where even the datasheet only claims 64.0 fps. I am curious to see if their API will act the same on Debian.

[image: Incoming Image]

Comment: What's the benefit of avoiding creating a BGAPI2::Image* ? Would that mean that the image data is copied once instead of twice?