# C++ code Capturing image from IP / Ethernet Cameras (AXIS Cam)

Tags: c++, opencv, ip-camera

I've 4 Axis IP cams. I need a code to capture image from those cams. I've opencv code to capture image from USB cams but I don't kno how to capture from IP cams.

Answer (score 3):

```
int main()
{
    Mat frame;
    namedWindow("video", 1);
    VideoCapture cap("http://150.214.93.55/mjpg/video.mjpg");
    while ( cap.isOpened() )
    {
        cap >> frame;
        if(frame.empty()) break;

        imshow("video", frame);
        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

no idea, how your urls look like, but opencv seems to insist, it has to end with mjpg.
so if it doesn't,  the trick is to append a dummy parameter:

```
http://my/cool/ip-cam.ie?dummy=video.mjpg
```

if you need to open all 4 cams at once, you need a VideoCapture for each one:

```
VideoCapture cap1("url1");
VideoCapture cap2("url2");
VideoCapture cap3("url3");
VideoCapture cap4("url4");
```

Comment: hello.cpp:3:5: error: ‘Mat’ was not declared in this scope
hello.cpp:3:9: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘frame’
hello.cpp:4:27: error: ‘namedWindow’ was not declared in this scope
hello.cpp:5:5: error: ‘VideoCapture’ was not declared in this scope
hello.cpp:5:18: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘cap’
hello.cpp:6:13: error: ‘cap’ was not declared in this scope
hello.cpp:8:16: error: ‘frame’ was not declared in this scope
hello.cpp:11:30: error: ‘imshow’ was not declared in this scope
hello.cpp:12:22: error: ‘waitKey’ was not declared in this scope