# Python OpenCV to capture mov video metadata

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

I read the following post [Getting video properties with Python without calling external software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47454317/getting-video-properties-with-python-without-calling-external-software) and [How can I identify a video format in Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817191/how-can-i-identify-a-video-format-in-python3) and [Extract metadata from a Video/Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22396761/extract-metadata-from-a-video-image) since my goal is to read my *.mov video file metadata.
My OpenCV version is 3.4.3 and I'm using the code as recommended in those discussions:

```
import cv2
vid = cv2.VideoCapture( 'test.mov')
height = vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT) # always 0 in Linux python3
width  = vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)  # always 0 in Linux python3
print ("opencv: height:{} width:{}".format( height, width))
```

However, both height and width are equal to 0. This cannot be possible.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: maybe you have to read first `frame` from stream. OR maybe `CV2` can't get this information for some video formats. Different format would need different code in `CV2` and someone would have to write it.

Comment: BTW: as I know `CV2` may use `ffmpeg` or `gstream` for this - so it also use `external` program. Maybe it will be simpler to use directly `ffmpeg` or module `ffmpeg-python` or `MoviePy`.

Comment: on `Linxu Mint 20.2` (based on `Ubuntu 20.04`) I used `ffmpeg` to convert file to `.mov`, `.avi`, `.mp4` and for all of them `cv2` gives me `height` and `width`. But I use the lastest `cv2` `'4.5.3'`

Comment: in your first link I found your code with text `MacOS and Linux packages do not support video related functionality (not compiled with FFmpeg)"` and `... opencv needs the presence of the binary packages of FFmpeg at runtime`

Comment: Double Check your path, cv2 returns a statement that looks like ```OpenCV: Couldn't read video stream from file "video.mov"
[ERROR:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (142) open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.5.1) ../modules/videoio/src/cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): video.mov in function 'icvExtractPattern'``` but allows you to continue your code

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused here. Isn't "vid = cv2.VideoCapture( 'test.mov')" supposed to open/read the video? it doesn't trigger any error message on my end.

Answer (score -3):

Replace .mov by .MOV and it should work.
vid = cv2.VideoCapture( 'test.MOV')

Comment: so you're assuming that OP is on a case-sensitive system and typed file name wrong? big assumption.