# Reading stream from IP camera with cv2.VideoCapture()

Tags: python, opencv

Referring to this similar question [How to parse mjpeg http stream from ip camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702477/how-to-parse-mjpeg-http-stream-from-ip-camera) I was able to read the stream from IP camera, by using `requests`:

```
stream = requests.get('http://<user>:<pass>@<addr>:<port>/videostream.cgi', stream=True)

bytez = ''
while True:
    bytez += stream.raw.read(16384)
    ...
```

and it works beautifully, but would like to get there by using `cv2.VideoCapture()` instead requests.

I tried variations in a manner of:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture()
cap.open('http://<user>:<pass>@<addr>:<port>/videostream.cgi?.mjpg')

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    ...
```

but wasn't able to get anything, but Exception about empty frame.

How to read IP camera stream with cv2.VideoCapture()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add C:\OpenCV\3rdparty\ffmpeg\ to the Windows PATH environment variable or copy opencv_ffmpeg.dll from that directory to C:\Python27. This has been answered in this question [OpenCV 2.4 VideoCapture not working on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699298/opencv-2-4-videocapture-not-working-on-windows)

Answer (score 3):

Pass the location of the camera in your `cap = cv2.VideoCapture()` line:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://<user>:<pass>@<addr>:<port>/videostream.cgi?.mjpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't yet tried accessing an IP camera from VideoCapture, but on your method 
`cap = cv2.VideoCapture()` the video capture is expecting a number representing the camera usually `0`.

By leaving it empty, it doesn't access any camera thus the Exception about an empty frame (even though later on you declare `cap.open()`, openCV already tried to open a camera and determined that is empty)

Comment: OpenCV: out device of bound (0-0): 1 ...  unless I pass 0 which is the laptop camera.  ifconfig shows the camera exists on en7.