# Creating a function using yield instead of return to generate frames from an http stream continuously

Tags: python, opencv, stream, iterator, python-requests

I would like to create a function that reads frames from an HTTP stream using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and returns each frame. But because of the fact that the stream reader is based on an iterator object (if I understand correctly), returning a frame is breaking the stream.

The code I am using (works perfectly fine, from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42904920/6331998) answer):

```
import cv2
import requests
import numpy as np

r = requests.get('http://roofcam.warwick.ac.uk/cgi-bin/faststream.jpg', stream=True)
if(r.status_code == 200):
    bytes_buffer = bytes()
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        bytes += chunk
        a = bytes_buffer.find(b'\xff\xd8')
        b = bytes_buffer.find(b'\xff\xd9')
        if a != -1 and b != -1:
            jpg = bytes_buffer[a:b+2]
            bytes_buffer = bytes_buffer[b+2:]
            i = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
            cv2.imshow('i', i)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
                exit(0)
else:
    print("Received unexpected status code {}".format(r.status_code))
```

Concept of what I'd like to do (with the return that I'd like to work if it was a while function instead of a for using iterator):

```
import cv2
import requests
import numpy as np

r = requests.get('http://roofcam.warwick.ac.uk/cgi-bin/faststream.jpg', stream=True)

def get_frame_from_stream(r):
    if(r.status_code == 200):
        bytes_buffer = bytes()
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            bytes_buffer += chunk
            a = bytes_buffer.find(b'\xff\xd8')
            b = bytes_buffer.find(b'\xff\xd9')
            if a != -1 and b != -1:
                jpg = bytes_buffer[a:b + 2]
                bytes_buffer = bytes_buffer[b + 2:]
                i = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(
                    jpg, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
                return i

    else:
        print("Received unexpected status code {}".format(r.status_code))
        return None

while True:
    if img is not None:
        img = get_frame_from_stream(r)
        cv2.imshow('i', img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
    else:
        break
```

So basically I'd like to return each frame where the original code is displaying the frame so that I can perform some processing on it. But I don't understand how exactly is the iter_content allowing the original code to work continuously.

(I didn't know how to name the question - will welcome a better title)

Comment: iter_content is a generator class I believe.

Comment: @0x52-0x75-0x63-0x79 thanks for your input. I did suspect that but I'm not sure if I can make it work like I described, and how to do that. I am trying to read about yield and generators but theory is one thing and I have a hard time trying to apply it in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python has a very beautiful concept of [`generators`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), which may be the thing you are looking for, so basically to fabricate a `generator` we use keyword [`yield`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement) instead of [`return`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement). The basic difference between these two keywords is that the `return` statement simply halts the function execution once encountered, while on the other hand `yield` keyword let's the execution to continue and keeps on generating value until alive. It can be visualized in a simple example as:

```
def sample_function():
    # The body would be replaced by image generating code.
    for i in xrange(20):
        yield i**2

for x in sample_function():
    print x, 
>>> 0 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100 121 144 169 196 225 256 289 324 361
```

If We would had reproduce the same scenario using `return` statement then it may look like:

```
def sample_function(i):
    return i**2

for i in xrange(0, 20):
    print sample_function(i),
```

So in the above code if you replace the `return` keyword with `yield`, then you can iterate the frames as:

```
for frame in get_frame_from_stream(r):
    cv2.imshow('i', frame)
```

There is no need of a `while` loop is this case, unless and until this stream is alive, the method would keep on generating frames.

Comment: Works like a charm. I did try doing it a little bit like that - using yield instead of return. But the 'for x in sample_function()' bit was a mystery to me and I tried using it like a normal function instead of in a 'for' statement. Thank you.