# How to capture android screen using python

Tags: android, python

I would like to do some image processing of my android screen using python (with opencv or other library).
I am a python programmer, thus don't want to use android studio or learn other tools for image processing just for this particular small task.

How can I connect my phone to stream its screen to my computer using python over usb/ip/anything else?

I also wouldn't mind writing the code in python and running it on android if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
But you need to use this app that is basically IP camera
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam

```
# Stream Video with OpenCV from an Android running IP Webcam (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam)
# Code Adopted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702477/how-to-parse-mjpeg-http-stream-from-ip-camera

import cv2
import urllib2
import numpy as np
import sys

host = "192.168.0.220:8080"
if len(sys.argv)>1:
    host = sys.argv[1]

hoststr = 'http://' + host + '/video'
print 'Streaming ' + hoststr

stream=urllib2.urlopen(hoststr)

bytes=''
while True:
    bytes+=stream.read(1024)
    a = bytes.find('\xff\xd8')
    b = bytes.find('\xff\xd9')
    if a!=-1 and b!=-1:
        jpg = bytes[a:b+2]
        bytes= bytes[b+2:]
        i = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8),cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
        cv2.imshow(hoststr,i)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) ==27:
            exit(0)
```