# Not able to GET video stream in openCV with Axis M3045 IP camera

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, deep-learning, facial-identification

i am trying to design new system in openCV but not able to capture stream from IP camera.

I've tried using different protocol like rtsp and http.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://root:pass@192.168.1.114/mjpg/video.mjpg')

    while(True):

    ret, frame = cap.read()





    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):

    break


   cap.release()
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[tcp @ 0x7ff4d705c440] Connection to tcp://192.168.1.114:80 failed: Operation timed out
OpenCV: Couldn't read video stream from file "http://root:pass@192.168.1.114/mjpg/video.mjpg"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "camera-test.py", line 14, in 
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /tmp/opencv-20190505-12101-14vk1fh/opencv-4.1.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:352: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'

Comment: I never managed to make it work with mjpg streams, but you can try a solution like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702477/how-to-parse-mjpeg-http-stream-from-ip-camera/21844162#21844162) or try the rtsp stream, googling a little you can see the link is more like: `rtsp://User:Pass@Camera_IP/axis-media/media.amp`. Sometimes you need to add a get parameter like `?whatever=.mp4` for the backend to know what codec to use....

Comment: Have you checked if you can see stream using VLC?

Comment: Guys i rest the camera and it done thing for me. Thank you