# Geting videostream from Baumer GigE Cameras and use it in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, gige-sdk

I'm trying to get a videostream from gigE Baumer txg12 camera, to use it in my openCV app. But I don't know how to achieve it.

Does anybody have experience with using Baumer SDK with openCV?
How can I get my video-stream?

Comment: I've never used a gigeE camera, but I remember seeing this flag when compiling OpenCV from source: ```WITH_GIGEAPI```. My guess is that once the gigE SDK is installed, you should be able to configure compiling OpenCV from source ```WITH_GIGEAPI``` via cmake, double check ```GIGEAPI_INCLUDE_PATH``` and ```GIGEAPI_LIBRARIES``` are set and pointing correctly to the installed gigE SDK, then compile and install OpenCV. In theory, once that's done, you should be able to access the camera via OpenCV's [VideoCapture](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#gsc.tab=0)

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345467/opencv-with-gige-vision-cameras/3350115. I believe it is still relevant. I use Basler GigE cameras with OpenCV and use the Basler native SDK.

Comment: @Nikita, I'm trying to do the same. I've successfully worked through Baumer's "programmers guide" which is provided in the "Docs" folder. Now I'm just trying to get openCV to display the image stream. I will update if I can get this working. Basler's API has a document on using openCV with their API, which might be an alternative route to follow. see [HERE](http://s.baslerweb.com/media/documents/AW00136801000_Getting_Started_with_pylon5_and_OpenCV.pdf)