# OpenCV with GigE Vision Cameras (Baumer) and Python

Tags: python, opencv, gige-sdk

I am trying to capture a GigE vision camera image with opencv python. I read some questions about capturing an image using the Baumer GAPI SDK with c++ [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345467/opencv-with-gige-vision-cameras/3350115#3350115). I am a python programmer and I want to ask is it possible to implement the same method for python. 
I read a another tutorial on Baumer webiste about ransfer images from Baumer GAPI to OpenCV c++ [HERE](https://www.baumer.com/dk/en/service-support/know-how/technical-information-industrial-cameras/baumer-gapi-and-opencv/a/baumer-gapi-and-opencv#understandingpixelformats)

Comment: I'm a developer at Pleora (eBUS SDK) and we're currently in the process of writing python bindings for our SDK which will allow you to write your entire application in python and use whichever libraries you like. It's still in progress but might be available for some early alpha testing soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need  to build Opencv from source  with GiGE support.  Or use external python  Library that supports GiGE like: 
https://github.com/genicam/harvesters